# Get table row count using multiple table join

Tags: mysql, join, rowcount

I have Three tables `company_m` , `client_m` , `companyuser_m`

**company_m**

```
 CompanyID  CompName    
----------+-----------
     7        Comp3 
     8        Comp2 
     9        Comp1 
     10       Company 
     11       Company4
```

**client_m**

```
clid    AttachToCompanyID   clname
-----+--------------------+------
  1           7             client1
  2           7             client2
  6           8             client3
```

**companyuser_m**

```
uid CompanyID   uname
---+---------+-------
 1    7         user1
 2    10        user2
```

**My Goal**

I need to get the count of all clients and users of the corresponding company

**Expected Output**

```
CompanyID   CompName    clientcount usercount
---------+-----------+--------------+--------
   7        Comp3          2           1
   8        Comp2          1           0
   9        Comp1          0           0
  10        Company 3      0           1
  11        Company4       0           0
```

**My Code**

```
select company_m.CompanyID,company_m.CompName,
count(client_m.AttachToCompanyID) as clientcount ,
count(companyuser_m.CompanyID) as usercount from company_m
left join client_m on client_m.AttachToCompanyID=company_m.CompanyID
left join companyuser_m on companyuser_m.CompanyID=company_m.CompanyID
group by company_m.CompanyID
```

But the above code not gives the correct output.

check my [**fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=3080c1b3932c333654571199d9c77830)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be left joining to separate subqueries which find the counts in the respective `client_m` and `companyuser_m` tables:

```
SELECT
    t1.CompanyID,
    t1.CompName,
    COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0) AS client_count,
    COALESCE(t3.cnt, 0) AS user_count
FROM company_m t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT AttachToCompanyID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM client_m
    GROUP BY AttachToCompanyID
) t2
    ON t1.CompanyID = t2.AttachToCompanyID
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT CompanyID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM companyuser_m
    GROUP BY CompanyID
) t3
    ON t1.CompanyID = t3.CompanyID;
```